# Odd "bank conflict"-type behavior with memcpy in CUDA global memory

Tags: performance, memory, cuda, global

I have distilled a performance issue down to the code shown below. This code takes an array of 128,000 64-byte structures ("Rule"s) and scatters them within another array. For example, if SCATTERSIZE is 10, then the code will copy ("scatter") 128,000 of these structures from the "small" array where they are stored contiguously at indices 0, 1, 2, ..., 127999, and place them at indices 0, 10, 20, 30, ..., 1279990 within the "big" array.

Here's what I can't figure out: On a device of compute capability 1.3 (Tesla C1060) performance suffers dramatically whenever SCATTERSIZE is a multiple of 16. And on a device of compute capability 2.0 (Tesla C2075) performance suffers quite a bit whenever SCATTERSIZE is a multiple of 24.

I don't think this can be a shared memory-bank thing, since I'm not using shared memory. And I don't think it can be related to coalescing. Using the commandline profiler and inspecting the "gputime" entry, I find a 300% increase in runtime on the 1.3 device, and a 40% increase in runtime on the 2.0 device, for the bad SCATTERSIZEs. I'm stumped. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
  float a[4][4];
} Rule;

#ifndef SCATTERSIZE
#define SCATTERSIZE 96
#endif

__global__ void gokernel(Rule* b, Rule* s){
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  memcpy(&b[idx * SCATTERSIZE], &s[idx], sizeof(Rule));
}


int main(void){
  int blocksPerGrid = 1000;
  int threadsPerBlock = 128;
  int numThreads = blocksPerGrid * threadsPerBlock;
  printf("blocksPerGrid = %d, SCATTERSIZE = %d\n", blocksPerGrid, SCATTERSIZE);

  Rule* small;      
  Rule* big;        

  cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc(&big, numThreads * 128 * sizeof(Rule));
  printf("Malloc big: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  err = cudaMalloc(&small, numThreads * sizeof(Rule));
  printf("Malloc small: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  gokernel <<< blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >>> (big, small);
  err = cudaThreadSynchronize();
  printf("Kernel launch: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
```

Comment: The `memcpy()` device function has a very basic implementation. It's just a loop that copies single bytes. Try using assignment instead. Something like `b[idx * SCATTERSIZE] = s[idx];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the implementation of `__device__` `memcpy` is hidden (it is a compiler built-in), it's hard to say what the cause is exactly. One hunch (thanks to njuffa on this one) is that it is what's known as partition camping, where addresses from many threads are mapping to one or a few physical DRAM partitions rather than being spread across them.

On SM 1_2/1_3 GPUs partition camping could be quite bad depending on the memory access stride, but this has been improved starting with SM_2_0 devices so that would explain why the effect is less pronounced.

You can often work around this effect by adding some padding into arrays to avoid offending offsets, but it may not be worth it depending on your computation.

Comment: partition camping was my thought too. the c1060 is the most prone to partition campingon the right power of 2 stride access patterns because it has 8 memory banks.

Comment: Could the 128-byte transaction size have something to do with it as well? Compute capability 2.0 accesses global memory in 128-byte transactions that are aligned to 128 bytes. So, a scattersize that causes many of the 32-byte structs to span 128-byte boundaries would increase the required number of transactions.

Comment: Well, it certainly won't help that the struct being copied is 64 bytes so with all but a stride of 1 you will be wasting half of each 128-byte transaction. But that will affect performance at more strides than just multiples of 16/24.

Comment: Thank you harrism for the note on "memcpy." I've been wondering how that works. Also, I looked up "partition camping," and that seems to be the notion that I've been unable to track down. From what I've read, it explains what I'm seeing very well. I'll try the suggestion on assignment given by Roger Dahl, and the padding you suggest. I'll post anything interesting I discover as comments here. Thank you!

Comment: I replaced all the memcpy calls with simple assignments, and got a four-fold increase in running time on the C2075! Partition camping is still present, but those cases also enjoy the 4-fold increase in speed. I have control over SCATTER size in my original application, and I've found that setting it to be <i>one more than</i> a multiple of 24 gives best results on the C2075. The increase in speed on the C1060 is 3.5, and I get the least amount of partition camping when the SCATTER size is one more than a multiple of 32. Thanks everyone!